# Best way to place inputs in viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am developing a view controller that contains multiple different input sources - checkbox, textfield, custom dropdown etc. I was developing it by creating a controller for each input source ('cause i need it in a different controllers in my app) and defining a frame

```
field.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(body.frame)/2 - width/2, UI_ELEMENT_Y_OFFSET * (self.parentSpinnerPos+2), width, UI_ELEMENT_HEIGHT);
```

Main problem was that i couldn't dynamically add an input in between some of those inputs generated when the view was loading without redrawing the positions of all inputs.

Now question: Am i correct that using autolayout and constraints is better way to program viewcontrollers with many inputs in it ? Or it is ok to define frames every time and redraw them if something changes.

Comment: Yes, autolayout is better!

Comment: If the configuration of input elements is fixed (or relatively fixed) then I would say that auto layout is better.  If you need to add controls in response to some data at runtime then programmatically is probably better, but you could look at containers like a tableview or collection view to simplify things